# recordtext is not updating in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am doing this in a function:

```
 $("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { recordtext: "View {0} - " + actualRows + " of " + actualRows });
```

but it is not being updated simultaneously in the recordtext in the gridpager. Actually I have debugged and saw that the value of  `$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', recordtext)` is getting updated according to my order but the effect is not there in the browser. what to do?

It's not a duplicate because that was an issue to put the database record count directly in the GridPager and this about putting recordtext and not refreshing accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "not being updated simultaneously"?

Comment: I want to mean though the the value `$("#UsersGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam','recordtext')` is updated to new value but it's not showing in the browser!!

Comment: Do you mean to have both values set to actualRows? As per the documentation do you have viewrecords set to true?

Comment: Yes, the updated version is not being shown. viewrecords is true and I can see the recordtext(string) at the bottom of the gridbut is not updated accordingly with the `setGridParam`

Comment: Any idea? How to reload only GridPager not the Grid?

Comment: Why would you only reload the GridPager? If you want a different value to show as part of the pager, modify the value on the server before it is passed down to the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the format of the recordtext property. The grid is expecting something in the format of

`recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",`

Comment: Actually I formatted the recordtext according to my calculation. I have debugged and the value is updating for the recordtext but the effect is not there in the browser.